# iOS: App with PDF-download, which method suggested? (ftp, rest, soap,..)

Tags: ios, rest, pdf, ftp, download

I'm quite to finishing my iPad app and only have to implement an PDF-download service. So when I want to download like 100 PDFs with my app in a row, which method would you suggest?

Actually I would think of FTP, but this doenst seem to be very safe anymore. On the other hand services like REST dont seem to be made for sending such big data (especially since being stateless and so).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS) is a widely-used communications protocol for secure communication over a computer network, with especially wide deployment on the Internet. Technically, it is not a protocol in itself; rather, it is the result of simply layering the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) on top of the SSL/TLS protocol, thus adding the security capabilities of SSL/TLS to standard HTTP communications.

Comment: Sounds good, can you suggest which frameworks I should use for xcode to implement this?

Comment: But the ASIHttprequest is out of date with its libraries. I already set it up once but it only throw errors because of the deprecated methods (garbage collection and so on)

Comment: Could I just use HTTPS with NSUrlconnection?!

Comment: My fault, dunno why I added the libs wrong the last time. Question answered, thank you very much!